# Create a table in existing report template using java

Tags: java, pentaho

I have created a prpt file using PRD 5.4.0.1 which contains a 2 labels 'Date' and 'Duration' which represent 2 columns of the table.These 2 labels are inside a inline subreport.I am trying to add textfields below these 2 labels and fill data obtained from a database query into them like this :

Date Duration

29-10-2015         2 hr 
30-10-2015         1 hr 
01-11-2015         1 hr 30 min

But the data does not appear in the generated pdf.Below is the code :

```
public class DataAccessVisitor extends AbstractStructureVisitor {

private DataSource dataSource;

private Connection connection;

private DateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd-MM-yyyy");

public void inspect(MasterReport report, String id, Date startDate,
        Date endDate) {

    ReportParameterDefinition rpd = report.getParameterDefinition();
    ParameterDefinitionEntry[] paramEntries = rpd.getParameterDefinitions();

    for (int i = 0; i < paramEntries.length; i++) {
        inspectParameter(report, rpd, paramEntries[i]);
    }
    inspectElement(report, id, startDate, endDate);
    traverseSection(report, id, startDate, endDate);
}

public void traverseSection(Section section, String id, Date startDate,
        Date endDate) {
    int count = section.getElementCount();

    ReportElement element = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        element = section.getElement(i);
        inspectElement(element, id, startDate, endDate);

        if (element instanceof Section) {
            traverseSection((Section) element, id, startDate, endDate);
        }
    }
}

public void inspectElement(ReportElement element, String id,
        Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    int i = 4;

    ResultSet rs = null;
    Map<String, Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> styleMap = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        if ("subreport1".equals(element.getName())) {

            ReportElement[] dateColumn = element
                    .getChildElementsByName("date_label");
            ReportElement[] durationColumn = element
                    .getChildElementsByName("duration_label");
            ReportHeader header = (ReportHeader) dateColumn[0]
                    .getParentSection();

            rs = getDataFromDB(id, startDate, endDate);
            styleMap.put("font-size", 15);
            styleMap.put("bold", false);

            while (rs.next()) {
                attributeMap.put("name", "date_textfield_" + (i-4));
                styleMap
                        .put("x",
                                ((Float) dateColumn[0].getStyle().getStyleProperty(StyleKey.getStyleKey("x"))));
                styleMap
                        .put("y",
                                i+((Float) dateColumn[0].getStyle().getStyleProperty(StyleKey.getStyleKey("y"))));
                Element date = createTextField(attributeMap);
                date.setAttribute(date.getAttributeNamespaces()[0],
                        "value", rs.getDate("startdate"));

                styleMap
                        .put("x",
                                ((Float) durationColumn[0].getStyle().getStyleProperty(StyleKey.getStyleKey("x"))));
                styleMap
                        .put("y",
                                i+((Float) durationColumn[0].getStyle().getStyleProperty(StyleKey.getStyleKey("y"))));
                attributeMap.put("name", "duration_textfield_" + (i-4));
                Element duration = createTextField(attributeMap);
                duration.setAttribute(duration.getAttributeNamespaces()[0],
                        "value", rs.getLong("duration"));

                header.addElement(date);
                header.addElement(duration);
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void inspectParameter(MasterReport report,
        ReportParameterDefinition rpd, ParameterDefinitionEntry entry) {
    System.out.println("Parameter name :" + entry.getName());
}

private Element createLabel(Map<String, Object> attributeMap) {
    LabelElementFactory labelFactory = new LabelElementFactory();
    labelFactory.setText(attributeMap.get("value") + "");
    labelFactory.setName(attributeMap.get("name") + "");
    labelFactory.setBold((Boolean) attributeMap.get("bold"));
    labelFactory.setFontSize((Integer) attributeMap.get("font-size"));
    Element label = labelFactory.createElement();
    return label;
}

private Element createTextField(Map<String, Object> attributeMap) {
    TextFieldElementFactory textFieldFactory = new TextFieldElementFactory();
    textFieldFactory.setName(attributeMap.get("name") + "");
    textFieldFactory.setFieldname(attributeMap.get("field") + "");
    textFieldFactory.setFontSize((Integer) attributeMap.get("font-size"));
    textFieldFactory.setBold((Boolean) attributeMap.get("bold"));
    textFieldFactory.setFieldname(attributeMap.get("field") + "");
    textFieldFactory.setX((Float) attributeMap.get("x"));
    textFieldFactory.setY((Float) attributeMap.get("y"));
    textFieldFactory.setVisible(true);
    Element textField = textFieldFactory.createElement();
    return textField;
}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    return connection;
}

public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do it via Pentaho Report Designer? You just need to create a query inside your subreport, move your text-fields to the details section and set "field" attributes of your text-fields to reference "startddate" and "duration" columns from your dataset. If text-fields are inside the details section, then they will get repeated for each row of your dataset with corresponding values.

Comment: Because I have to do additional processing for each row of the dataset before generating the report.

Comment: You may try to use in PRD scriptable datasource instead of SQL query then. Thus you will be able to write java-like code to process your dataset. Or, you may try to set custom DataFactory for your subreport in your java application. IMHO, this is more appropriate approach than adding report-elements for each row. If you still want to add new report-elements for each row: try to use labels instead of text-fields. Since text-fields may disregard the value attribute. And please, make sure, that your elements do not overlap. You may set header layout to block to avoid overlapping.

Comment: @user4637357 Thanks.It works now.Used TypedTableModel and TableDataFactory and moved the textfields to details section.

Comment: @user4637357 How to do the same for existing chart?I have tried CategorySetDataCollector and BarChartExpressionbut did not work.

Comment: Sorry, I have not yet worked with Pentaho charts in Java.I shall leave comment in the corresponding question if i will get any ideas.